# SSRS Expression - Subtract SUMS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I need some help with an SSRS expression that sums up amounts and then subtracts sums. I have a dataset that has accounts and corresponding money/amount values. I'm trying to write an expression that sums up the money/amount values from one group of the accounts in a specified range, and then subtracts it from the money/amount total of another range. For example:

```
(Sum(amt) where acct between 40000 and 49999) - 
(Sum(amt) where (acct between 50000 and 59999) or (acct between 66000 and 69999)) - 
(Sum(amt) where acct between 76000 and 79825) - 
(Sum(amt) where acct between 89000 and 90399)
```

I could really use some help translating the SQL logic above into an expression to be used for a textbox in SSRS. Any advice would be really helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :-

```
=Sum(
     iif(Fields!acct.Value) >= 1 and
         Fields!acct.Value) < 4 ,
     Fields!amt.Value,0
        )
    )
-
 Sum(
     iif(
         (Fields!acct.Value>=5 and Fields!acct.Value<10)
          or (Fields!acct.Value>=12 and Fields!acct.Value< 15),
          Fields!amt.Value,0 
         )
    )
-
Sum(
     iif(
         Fields!acct.Value) >= 76000 and
         Fields!acct.Value) < 79825 ,
         Fields!amt.Value,0
         )
   )
-
Sum(
   iif(
       Fields!acct.Value) >= 89000 and
       Fields!acct.Value) < 90399 ,
   Fields!amt.Value,0
       )
    )
```

Comment: Thank you Praveen. This ultimately worked, although I had to do some conversion and aggregating on my end.  Also, I used 'NOTHING' instead of '0' in the Boolean.